# Lambda as a leaky state machine?

Tags: firebase, lambda, firebase-authentication, aws-lambda

I have a micro-service which involved in an OAuth 1 interaction. I'm finding myself in a situation where two runs of the Lambda functions with precisely the same starting states have very different outcomes (where state is considered the "event" passed in, environment variables, and "stageParameters" from the API Gateway).

Here's a Cloudwatch log that shows two back-to-back runs:
[image]

You can see that while the starting state is identical, the execution path changes pretty quickly. In the second case (failure case), you see the log entry "Auth state changed: null" ... that is very odd indeed because in fact this is logged **before** even the first line of code of the "handler" is executed. Here's the beginning of the functions handler:

```
export const handler = (event, context, cb) => {
  console.log('EVENT:\n', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
```

So where is this premature logging entry coming from? Well, one must assume that it somehow is left over from prior executions. Let me demonstrate ... it is in fact an event listener that was setup in the prior execution. This function interacts with a Firebase DB and the first time it connects it sets the following up:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
  .then((result) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.watchAuthState);
```

where the `watchAuthState` function is simply:

```
watchAuthState(user) {
  console.log(`Auth state changed:\n`, JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
}
```

This seems to mean that when I run the DB a second time I am already "initialized" with the Firebase DB but apparently the authentication has been invalidated. My number one aim is to just get back to a predictive state model and have it execute precisely the same each time.

If, there are sneaky ways to reuse cached state between Lambda executions in resource useful ways then I guess that too would be interesting but only if we can do that while achieving the predictive state machine.

Comment: I would guess this is due to a bug in your code due to improper handling of JavaScript asynchronous calls. Can you post your entire Lambda Function?

Comment: not very easily ... it's typescript and closed source. How do you explain that the first line of execution in the handler function is not the first to log?

Comment: OK I see what you are saying now, posting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the logs order, look at the ID that comes after each timestamp at the beginning of each line. I believe this is the invocation ID. In the two lines you have highlighted in orange, they are from different invocations of the function. The `EVENT` log is the first line to get logged from the invocation with ID ending in `754ee`. The `Auth state changed: null` line is a log entry coming from the earlier invocation of the function with invocation ID ending in `c40d5`.

It looks like you are setting auth state to null at the end of an invocation, but the Firebase connection is global, so the second function invocation thinks the Firebase connection is already initialized, but then it throws errors because the authentication was nulled out.

> My number one aim is to just get back to a predictive state model and
>   have it execute precisely the same each time.

Then you need to be aware of [Lambda container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/), and not use any global variables.

Comment: Good catch on the invocation ID and it does validate what I was saying about being leftover from the prior run. With Typescript I had been keeping the connection stored as a singleton/static member of my Database module and it appears that is where the problem lay. By bringing all state back into the scope of the instance(s) the state machine becomes whole again.

Comment: it does make me wonder if there is a stable yet more optimised way of doing this but I presume the websocket connection would always be lost and really that would be the nicest optimisation I'd be wanting to achieve. For now, i'll just stick with deterministic state. :)